# Error while configuring WSO2 APIM Analytics 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed the quick setup steps given in the documentation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/) to configure WSO2 APIM Analytics 3.1.0.

1. The worker profile of the analytics server starts well.
2. The WSO2 APIM server starts well.
3. But when I start the dashboard profile of the analytics server, I am getting the below error and the dashboard portal doesn't open. But at the end it shows as analytics server started.

Need suggestions to fix this issue. I am using jdk-8.0.202.08.

> ```
> ERROR {msf4j-core} - [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = microservice, interface =
> ```
>
> org.wso2.msf4j.Microservice, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..n,
> target = null, bind = addService, unbind = removeService]
> Details:
> Problematic reference = Reference[name = microservice, interface = org.wso2.msf4j.Microservice, policy = dynamic, cardinality
> = 0..n, target = null, bind = addService, unbind = removeService]
> of service component = org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroServicesServerSC
> component implementation class = org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC
> located in bundle with symbolic name = msf4j-core
> bundle location = reference:file:../lib/plugins/msf4j-core_2.7.7.jar
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:444)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.register(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:154)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.lambda$register$3(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:144)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar$$Lambda$282.00000000136A32F0.apply(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
> at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:496)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
> at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.register(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:145)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.listener.AppTransportBinder.appDeploymentEvent(AppTransportBinder.java:76)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.io.deployment.ArtifactAppDeployer.publishAppDeploymentEvent(ArtifactAppDeployer.java:154)
> at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.io.deployment.ArtifactAppDeployer.deploy(ArtifactAppDeployer.java:103)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine$$Lambda$237.0000000015CDC120.accept(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
> at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
> at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
> at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager$$Lambda$159.0000000013AD3830.accept(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
> at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
> at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
> at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
> at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:146)
> at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:135)
> at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addMicroserviceToRegistry(MicroservicesServerSC.java:421)
> at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addService(MicroservicesServerSC.java:108)
> ... 50 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Class$Atomic
> at org.wso2.msf4j.util.RuntimeAnnotations.(RuntimeAnnotations.java:110)
> ... 52 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Class$Atomic
> at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:332)
> at org.wso2.msf4j.util.RuntimeAnnotations.(RuntimeAnnotations.java:58)
> ... 52 more

Comment: Did you add this config to deployment.toml ?                                                          `[apim.analytics]
  enable = true`

Answer (score 0):

make sure all 3 components are under same directory

use open jdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232-3
for me it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like APIM analytics doesn't support Open JDK. Can you refer to this issue[1]? Also, do the same test with Oracle JDK and check this is reproduced in there as well.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/issues/944